# How do I go back to the previous pages without overloading them in the web view?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

my application reloads pages in webview, when returning to previous pages, how do I return to previous pages without overloading them?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar_FullScreen);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web)
    setFullscreen()

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
    val settings: WebSettings = webView.settings
    settings.domStorageEnabled = true

    val extras = intent.extras
    if (extras != null)
        webView.loadUrl("${extras.getString(Constants.SEND_LINK_IN_WEB_VIEW)}")

    cookie(extras?.getString(Constants.SEND_LINK_IN_WEB_VIEW)!!)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack()
    } else {
        Log.d("MyTag", "onBackPressed")
    }
}
```